# Including kendo.all.min.js in karma.conf.js for unit testing

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a project in angular js using kendo.directives that need to be tested. But whenever I tried to load kendo.all.min.js in karma.conf.js file I get the following error:
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){"bundle all";!function(e,t,n){function i(){}function r(e,t)

not getting any clue what to do? so please help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you have a solution?

Comment: yes open the kendo.all.min.js and there replace all define keyword by definex it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution in this way:-
I opened *kendo.all.min.js* and replaced the keywords **define** by **definex**. The problem occurs because of the conflicting define keyword of *kendo.all.min.js* and *Require.js*